# Run a python script in HTML button using JQuery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, webapp2

I have a python script that I want to be executed when I click a button on html page. I am using JQuery to do so. 
For some reason, it just doesn't do anything. Am I missing any permissions or some syntax? Not sure.

I am using WebApp2 framework for my application.

Here is the code.

```html
<input type="button" name="" value="run" onclick="goscript()">
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  function goscript(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"fb.py",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function(){
      alert('finished python script');;
    });
  }
</script>
```

My python file is in same html directory where the template is.

I am pretty new to coding, Any suggestions or help please.

Comment: Read this from beginning to end: https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: python doesn't execute on browser.. you need to develop rest service using python (server code) and then call that url to fetch data... start learning about rest api and backend programming.. then you will start understanding... try to differentiate backend and frontend... 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsQ1tFLwldY
    https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

Comment: Can you please clarify, how would the REST API help me with this? I am assuming, when the user will hit the button on webpage, it will send a request to server and the server will execute the command line. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @jaspreetsohal I think maybe you can try and use the Fetch API for your purpose? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API